# Conditionally apply filter in forward pipe chain in F#?

Tags: f#, conditional-statements

I get a sequence of records from a CSV file.  I want to optionally filter those records by date and type and optionally consolidate records meeting certain criteria.  Optionally filtering by date and type is straightforward using `Seq.filter`.  However I would like to optionally consolidate records meeting certain criteria.  I have the function working, I just can't figure out how to optionally apply it to the resulting sequence.  I can't use Seq.filter because consolidate operates on the entire sequence not on one item at a time.  I can solve it with an intermediate variable, I was just wondering if there was a graceful idiomatic way to handle this.

Basically I want to know a way to conditionally apply one (or more) parts of the chain in a forward pipe sequence.

This is what I want in pseudo code (`options` holds command line parameters):

```
let x =
    getRecords options.filePath
    |> Seq.filter (fun r -> if options.Date.HasValue then
                            r.Date.Date = options.Date.Value.Date else true)
    |> Seq.filter (fun r -> if not(String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Type)) then
                            r.Type = options.Type else true)
    if options.ConsolidateRecords then
        |> consolidateRecords
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an `if ... else` expression with the identity function in `else` clause:

```
let x =
    getRecords options.filePath
    |> (* ... bunch of stuff ... *)
    |> (if options.ConsolidateRecords then consolidateRecords else id)
    |> (* ... optionally more stuff ... *)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like

```
let x =
    getRecords options.filePath
    |> Seq.filter (fun r -> if options.Date.HasValue then
                            r.Date.Date = options.Date.Value.Date else true)
    |> Seq.filter (fun r -> if not(String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Type)) then
                            r.Type = options.Type else true)
    |> fun x ->
         if options.ConsolidateRecords then x |> consolidateRecords
         else ....
```

Comment: I like it.  So to do nothing when `options.ConsolidateRecords` is false then the else clause would just return `x`?  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Do you want to take a screenshot of your 7777 score before I upvote this? I feel bad upvoting it lol

Comment: @User Either return x or continue processing, whichever you would have otherwise done.

Answer (score 3):

You could also shadow the previous definition of `x`:

```
let x =
    getRecords options.filePath
    |> Seq.filter (fun r -> 
        not options.Date.HasValue || r.Date.Date = options.Date.Value.Date)
    |> Seq.filter (fun r -> 
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Type) || r.Type = options.Type)
let x = if options.ConsolidateRecords then consolidateRecords x else x
```